# Помогите в написании регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но надо из папки с названием

> [каталог0] - 01.01.1970_Каталог1ёКаталог2

сделать

> [каталог0] - 01.01.1970 - Каталог2 - Каталог1

То есть, поменять местами всё от знака "_" до буквы "ё" и от буквы "ё" до конца строки. Допёр только до того, что

```
(ё.+)$
```

это то, что стоит после "ё", а

```
(_.*ё)
```

это первая часть. А вот как это всё объединить в одно регулярное выражение? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто взять и [объединить](https://regex101.com/r/q0BE1K/1).

```
(.+)_(.+)ё(.+)$
```